# mvc3 json result returning a file

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Here's my situation: i have a dialog form that inserts some data on my database. After everything is validate, the form info is turned to a database object (i'm using linq to sql) and is submitted. 
Since i'm doing this using jquery ajax, i have a success function that displays some message to the user (just to inform him that his action was successful), closes my dialog and refresh my main page. And that's the problem, none of the success actions are occuring due some strange download window that's showing up, asking me if i want to download my controller action (you'll se on my code).

Here's the reducted code:

**JQuery Submit Function**

```
     //Submete a nova solicitão ao servidor e atualiza a página em caso de sucesso
            $("#novaSIForm").submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: $(this).attr("action"),
                    cache: false,
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        //Fecha a modal
                        $("#novaSIModal").dialog("close");
                        //Após a requisição ter sucesso, atualiza a página
                        $("#SiContainer").load('@Url.Action("SolicitacoesInternas")');

                        alert(data.msg);
                    },
error: function (jqr, errorStatus, errorThrow) {
                    alert("Erro ocorrido " + errorStatus);
                }
                });

                return false; //Isso faz com o que o form não execute sua ACTION
            });
```

**ACTION**

```
public ActionResult SiNovaSI(ChamadoViewModel chVM, string tituloChamado)
        {
            try
            {
                CHAMADO ch = new CHAMADO();

                ch.InjectFrom(chVM);//Injeta os valores da ViewModel no novo Chamado criado
                //Seta outras propriedades que não foram injetadas anteriormente
                ch.DATAINICIO = DateTime.Now;
                ch.SOLICITANTE = ((USUARIO)Session["UsuarioLogado"]).NOMEREDUZIDO;
                ch.STATUS = "SOLICITADO";
                ch.VALORDEBITO = ((DEBITO)Session["Debitos"]).VALORPARCELA;


                ChamadoManager chMan = new ChamadoManager();

                chMan.InsertCHAMADO(ch);//Insere o novo chamado no banco de dados

                return Json(new { sucesso = true, msg = "Chamado cadastrado com sucesso" });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Json(new { sucesso = false, algo = "Nao foi possível registrar o chamado. Erro: " + e.Message });
            }

        }
```

**Image**

[image]

Oh, i forgot to mention that i have included all the necessary jquery scripts. Including some MS Ajax scripts (even though i'm no longer using it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this `#novaSIForm` was dynamically generated (maybe after an AJAX call) you might loose your `.submit` handler if the DOM element is replaced. So you could use the `.live` method. Also make sure that this event subscription happens inside the `document.ready` event handler (in the case you are using `.submit` instead of `.live`)

```
$('#novaSIForm').live('submit', function() {
    ...
    return false;
});
```

Also inspect with FireBug the actual AJAX request that is being sent and that there are no javascript errors occurring.

Comment: thanks for your correct answer. It appears that DOM element was being replaced. Now what i don't understand is why has it worked today, considering that tried that yesterday. In fact, using ".live" has fired my submit event twice. Anyway, thanks for que quick answer.

Comment: @Adriano-RR, maybe you have another `.submit` event registration? In addition to the `.live`. You actually see 2 AJAX requests being triggered in FireBug?

Comment: unless my Html.BeginForm() is firing it's own submit, i don't any other submits. It's my dialog button that calls my submit through $("#novaSIForm").submit(). And yes, firebug is showing 2 POST requests and 2 GET (it's due my .load event). Do you want to see the entire code?

Comment: @Adriano-RR, if you properly cancel the default submission by returning false from the .submit handler the form should not be submitted twice. The only thing that I can think of is that there are somehow two .submit handlers registered for this form.

Comment: The first time i fire my submit action, it only happens once. But if try to do a second insert, the submit fires twice. It seems that i'm not replacing my DOM by calling the load event. Maybe i should not call the load event from inside the ajax success function.

Comment: @Adriano-RR, if you can email me a narrowed down version of an MVC application illustrating the issue I would be glad to take a look at it and help you because from your question I don't know where the problem might be.

Comment: i've solved it by setting $(selector).die("submit"). I know that this is a hack, but i couldn't figured out how do fix my double submission problem. I can email you with a narrowed solution if you think this hack may cause me problem in future. Anyway, thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

In the Ajax call, it might be worth explicitly specifying Json as the return type you're expecting:

```
dataType: "json",
```

Comment: even though i haven't posted it yesterday, i tried to pass several different datatypes and none of them was successful, json included. In fact, i've tested it 2 minutes ago.